# How to Find the Spectrum of an Integral Operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory, integral-operators

I need to find the spectrum of an operator $T: C([0,1]) \to C([0,1])$ defined by $(Tf)(t) = \int_0^t f(x) dx$. I know that the spectrum is the set of all values $\lambda$ such that $\lambda I - T$ is *not* invertible, but I'm not sure how to go about finding those values when integrals are involved. I've found several other posts about finding the spectrum of an integral operator here, but they all seem to involve functions of two variables, and that's throwing me off.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that the Volterra operator is a Hilbert-Schmidt operator and therefore is compact. The Fredholm alternative yields that if $\lambda\in\sigma(T)$, $\lambda\ne 0$, then $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$. It can be shown that the only eigenvalue of $T$ is $0$, whence the spectrum of $T$ is $\{0\}$.

Comment: Neither Hilbert-Schmidt operators nor the Fredholm alternative has come up in class (this is the first I'm learning of them), so I'm not sure I'm allowed to use them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The resolvent $(T-\lambda I)^{-1}$ is obtained by solving for $g$ in the following:
$$
                      g = (T-\lambda I)^{-1}f \\
                  (T-\lambda I)g= f \\
                \int_0^x g(t)dt-\lambda g(x)=f(x) \\
             \int_0^xg(t)dt-\lambda\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^x g(t)dt=f(x) \\
        \frac{d}{dx}\int_0^xg(t)dt-\frac{1}{\lambda}\int_0^x g(t)dt=-\frac{1}{\lambda}f(x) \\
       \frac{d}{dx}\left(e^{-x/\lambda}\int_0^xg(t)dt\right)=-\frac{1}{\lambda}e^{-x/\lambda}f(x) \\
       e^{-x/\lambda}\int_0^x g(t)dt = -\frac{1}{\lambda}\int_0^x e^{-u/\lambda} f(u)du \\
       \int_0^xg(t)dt=-\frac{1}{\lambda}\int_0^x e^{(x-u)/\lambda}f(u)du \\
        g(x)=-\frac{1}{\lambda}f(x)-\frac{1}{\lambda^2}\int_0^x  e^{(x-u)/\lambda}f(u)du
$$
So,
$$
   (T-\lambda I)^{-1}f = -\frac{1}{\lambda}f(x)-\frac{1}{\lambda^2}\int_0^x  e^{(x-u)/\lambda}f(u)du
$$
and the spectrum is $\sigma(T)=\{0\}$.

Comment: Is there a reason you knew using an exponential would work?

Comment: @Sarah : The resolvent is a first order linear ODE. You just need an integrating to solve it.

Comment: Ah, I see. I really need to brush up on ODEs; I haven't worked with them in a while.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach is to use the spectral radius formula $r(T) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \|T^n\|^{1/n}$.  By induction, you show that
$$ T^n f(t) = \int_0^t \frac{(t-x)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} f(x) \, dx .$$
So $\|T^n\| = 1/n!$, and $\|T^n\|^{1/n} \to 0$.

Comment: If the limit isn't zero, will I have to go back to the previous method, or are there more tricks? :)

Comment: This particular method only works if the spectrum is $\{0\}$.

Answer (score 1):

The spectrum is $\{0\}$. To prove let $c \neq 0$ and this consider the equation $Tf-\frac  1 c f=g$ where $g \in C[0,1]$. If $h=Tf$ this becomes  $h-\frac  1c h'=g$ or $h'-ch=-cg$. Hence $(e^{-cx}h(x))'=-ce^{-cx} g(x)$. Integrating we get $h(x)=e^{cx} [C-\int_0^{x}e^{-ct} g(t) dt]$ for some constant $C$. Since $h(0)=0$ we get $C=0$. Next $f =h'=(-e^{cx} \int_0^{x}e^{-ct} g(t) dt)'$.  Now it is quite easy to see that $\|f\| \leq M \|g\|$ for a constant $M$ independent of $g$.   We have proved that for every $g$ there is a unique solution $f$ for $Tf-\frac  1 c f=g$ and that that map $g \to f$ is continuous. This means that $T-\frac  1 c I$ has  a bounded inverse whenever $c \neq 0$.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you knew using an exponential would work?