# Integral operator and it’s spectrum

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, operator-theory, spectral-theory

I am doing some functional analysis and am struggling with the following exercise:
Let $T$ be an integral operator defined as followed:
$$T(f)(s)=\int_0^1(s-t)^2f(t)dt$$
I am asked to it’s spectrum. I did/think the following:

I think this operator is compact thus it suffices to find all the eigenvalues. I.e. all the $\lambda\in\mathbb R$ satisfying: $\lambda f=T(f)$. After I tried some functions for $f$, I noticed that $T$ sends any integrable function to a polynomial of at most degree 2. So the eigenvalues are polynomials of at most degree 2.

Note: this is just my intuition I have not yet been able to make it rigorous. My questions are:

- Am I on the right track?
- How can I make this rigorous for a random integrable function $f$ instead of examples?
- How do I find the eigenvalues given the eigenvectors are polynomials of at most degree 2?

Thank u :)

Comment: If $f(t)=1$, $T(f)$ is a cubic polynomial in $s$...

Comment: What exactly is the domain of the operator?

Comment: The exercise did not state the domain I think $C[0, 1]$, but I also believe $L^2 [0, 1]$ also works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spectrum of a self-adjoint integral operator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4005598/spectrum-of-a-self-adjoint-integral-operator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, $T$ sends integrable functions to polynomials of at most degree **2**. To see that this is the case, note that the integral can be expanded to
$$
Tf = \left(\int_0^1 f(t)\,dt\right)s^2
- 2\left(\int_0^1 tf(t)\,dt\right)s
+ \left(\int_0^1 t^2f(t)\,dt\right).
$$
Other than that, your argument is correct. To prove that this kind of operator is generally compact, you could use one of the arguments [presented here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1001185/81360). In this case, however, it suffices to note that the image of $T$ is finite-dimensional.

From there, we can determine the eigenvectors of $T$ as follows. Consider the restriction of $T$ to the space $\Bbb P_2$ of degree-2 polynomials. Relative to the basis $\mathcal B = (1,t,t^2)$, we find that the matrix of the restriction $T|_{\Bbb P_2}$ is given by
$$
[T]_{\mathcal B} = 
\pmatrix{\frac 13 & \frac 14 & \frac 15\\ 
-1& -\frac 23 & -\frac 12 \\
1& \frac 12 & \frac 13}.
$$

The eigenvalues of this operator are the non-zero elements of the spectrum of $T$.

You should find that these are equal to $-1/6$ and $(5 \pm 3\sqrt{5})/60$.

Comment: If we restrict our map does that not change the spectrum? Thanks for answering! :)

Comment: @Main It does not. In general, restricting a map to an invariant subspace yields a subset of the spectrum. You might find it to be a helpful exercise to convince yourself that each eigenvector of this matrix corresponds to a degree-2 polynomial that works as an eigenfunction of $T$.